# Istio with NFS-server comunication

Tags: kubernetes, istio, nfs

I'm discovering NFS-server on GKE cluster. However I have problem with connecting to disk if the NFS-server is deployed with sidecar istio proxy container.
In the log there is only:

```
Mount system call failed
```

Without sidecar, everything works well and I can easily mount disk using NFS. Does anybody know how to configure istio to allow internal access to nfs-server’s service?
Below my configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: nfs-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: nfs-server
      containers:
      - name: nfs-server
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
        ports:
          - name: nfs
            containerPort: 2049
          - name: mountd
            containerPort: 20048
          - name: rpcbind
            containerPort: 111
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /exports
            name: nfs-pvc
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-pvc
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: storage-nfs
            fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
spec:
  ports:
    - name: nfs
      port: 2049
    - name: mountd
      port: 20048
    - name: rpcbind
      port: 111
  selector:
    role: nfs-server
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: nfs-server.default.svc.cluster.local
    path: "/"

---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc-1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv-demo-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nfs-pv-demo
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nfs-pv-pod
      labels:
        app: nfs-pv-demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        name: nfs-pv-multi
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: busybox
        volumeMounts:
          # name should match from volumes section
          - name: nfs-volume-1
            mountPath: "/disk1"
      volumes:
      - name: nfs-volume-1
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nfs-pvc
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knoing your Istio verions, try to bypass the NFS traffic by adding an `excludeInboundPorts` annotation ([Alpha feature status currently](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/annotations/)) to your NFS server deployment:

```
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: nfs-server
      annotations:
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: "111,2049,20048"
```

Comment: I can use this feature, I tried, but it dosen't work